# Can't open site in SharePoint Designer

Tags: sharepoint-designer

I'm trying to open a sharepoint site in SPD with no success. 
SPD is processing, and nothing happens, it keeps processing as if it wouldn't find the site.

Do you have any clue where it comes from ?

For information I'm using the Site administration for this and the SPDSettings of the Web Application are all set to true.

EDIT : After waiting for 10 minutes I had this error : 
Service Unavailable
   Service Unavailable HTTP Error 503. The service is unavailable.

EDIT 2 : I think this error comes from the fact that i was deploying another solution in the same web application, but in another site collection ...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your question is unfortunately too general to provide a specific answer. The SharePoint designer communicates to your SharePoint site via a series of web services to pull down the information. There's probably issues going on during these requests. Have you tried logging into the SharePoint Designer as the System Account in order to dismiss any security issues with the site contents?

To diagnose the source of these issues, review the ULS logs that are created during the period of trying to access the designer. These can be reviewed at:

```
\\<Server Name>\c$\Program Files\Common Files\Microsoft Shared\Web Server Extensions\14\LOGS
```

Use [ULS Log Viewer](http://www.google.co.uk/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&source=web&cd=1&ved=0CCYQFjAA&url=http://archive.msdn.microsoft.com/ULSViewer&ei=vGuaT8eXHsiG4gSX6uSlDw&usg=AFQjCNEOHo87LLj0Gc_rOwp6O5Tg4tZzfQ&sig2=x1D0ArflXaBeJ1gIXATocA) to provide a real time view of all the log entries SharePoint creates during your usage.

Comment: Hey, yeah sorry i didn't know how to check for more informations. I Found this in the logs :
Alternate access mappings have not been configured.  Users or services are accessing the site http://y000zvk:7878 with the URL http://localhost:7878.  This may cause incorrect links to be stored or returned to users.  If this is expected, add the URL http://localhost:7878 as an AAM response URL.  For more information, see: http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkId=114854"/>

Comment: It may be that you've not correctly set up the AAMs and when the designer opens it's using a non compatible URL for it's service requests. Here's a Mircosoft training video covering the concept: http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/sharepoint/Video/ff679917

Comment: Hey, thanks for the help. Unfortunately I can't see Video in my company. But I think I know what i have to do : http://technet.microsoft.com/en-en/library/cc288609.aspx
The problem now is that i don't get it to see the link "Extend or create Web Application" ...

Comment: It's okay, I found it :)

Comment: @user1056832: Great, glad you got it sorted. Also, a quick tip, in the future you'll probably get your SharePoint questions answered quicker on the SharePoint dedicated stack exchange site: http://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/